# Pytest iterate over test function result

Tags: python, pytest

I have two lists `INPUT` and `EXPECTED`, where each item in the first list is the parameter for my test function `my_test_function`. This function returns an instance of a class called `A`, it has an attribute called `a` which is the one I want to test, the problem is that that attribute is a list of variable length (which depends on the input my test function received), for simplicity let's say the elements of that list are integers (they are actually instances of another class). Then if the `INPUT[i]` produces a result of lenght `n_i`, the corresponding `OUTPUT[i]` is a list of the same lenght with its expected values.

I currently have my test drawn up as follows

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inp, output", zip(INPUT, OUTPUT))
def test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow(inp, output):
    result = my_test_function(inp)
    for res_a, exp_res in zip(result.a, output):
        assert res_a == exp_res
```

I want to parametrize also the loop, I don't like the test to stop at the first unfulfilled `assert`, I would like to know how many results were different from those expected in the `res_a` list at once.

Comment: Is there any problem with `assert result.a == output` or `assert list(result.a) == list(output)` if they're not the same type? When you run pytest with `-vv` it should give you a full diff of which elements differed in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible using parametrization that way. The problem is that you want to parametrize the output of your tested function, so you have to know that value before parametrizing it.

In principle this is possible if moving the actual call of the test code out of the test to create the wanted parametrization dynamically using `pytest_generate_tests`:

```py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if all(p in metafunc.fixturenames
           for p in ("input", "output", "expected")):
        params = []
        for input, expected in zip(INPUT, OUTPUT):
            output = my_test_function(input)
            for value, expected_value in zip(output, expected):
                params.append((input, value, expected_value))
        metafunc.parametrize(["input", "output", "expected"], params)

def test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow(input, output, expected):
    assert output == expected
```

This would do what you want, but is kind of a hacky solution, and I'm not sure what kind of unwanted side effects this may have.

You could use something like [pytest-check](https://pypi.org/project/pytest_check/) instead which prevents the asserts to end the test:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("inp, output", zip(INPUT, OUTPUT))
def test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow(inp, output):
    result = my_test_function(inp)
    for res_a, exp_res in zip(result, output):
        with check:
            assert res_a == exp_res
```

Note though that in this case you don't get the extensive information you usually get from a failed assert. If you you had a couple of failures in one of the tests, you would get something like this:

```
$ python -m pytest -v test_parametrize.py
...
collected 3 items

test_parametrize.py::test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow[a-output0] PASSED                                    test_parametrize.py::test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow[b-output1] PASSED                                    test_parametrize.py::test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow[c-output2] FAILED                                    
============================= FAILURES ===============================
__________ test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow[c-output2] ___________
FAILURE: assert 5 == 7
  +5
  -7
test_parametrize.py:36 in test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow() -> assert res_a == exp_res
FAILURE: assert 7 == 9
  +7
  -9
test_parametrize.py:36 in test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow() -> assert res_a == exp_res
------------------------------------------------------------
Failed Checks: 2
====================== short test summary info =======================
FAILED double_parametrize.py::test_example_to_ask_in_stackoverflow[c-output2]
==================== 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.41s =====================
```